# Create excel budget calendar by cross-referencing a column and row

Tags: excel

I created a calendar in Excel in which I would like to reference transactional data in the days.  The calendar is setup as follows:

Sun, Jan 1 Starts with the balance from 12/31/16, and has a simple carryover formula throughout the week/month:

[image]

Over to the right is the "Nitty Gritty"

The more detailed budget data:

[image]

I thought the correct formula would be:

`=SUMIF(O3:O7,C2,VLOOKUP(A6,N3:R7,5,FALSE))`, but seem to run into an error.  It seems the solution would be so simple, any advice?  I'd like to not constantly copy/paste every time I update the data to the right....Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you supply the entire relevant portion of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the layout of your output, I would heavily advise a pivot table. you can have as many calculated fields as you like (though much easier to control in your source data a calculated fields in your source table). After using calculated fields to determine the layout, the pivot table will summarize all values for the respective day and expense type for you, automatically.

If I have misunderstood, please provide the relevant details that Brian Leeming had requested.

Comment: I also tried a Pivot table at first, but couldn't get the desired parameters.  I'll try again.

Comment: It seems you'd want to have the dates as your columns and the designation as the rows. If this doesn't result in the desired effect, please do provide the details Brian Leeming had requested. Once we see the reference ranges as shown in your SUMIFS formula, we can provide more guidance.